# Hold keys for accented like on macOS

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 21.10

On macOS and iOS, you have the ability to hold down a key and select an accented character or symbol. Is there some sort of package or gnome extension that I can install for Ubuntu?

(I tried searching for this specific solution, no helpful results, or out-of-date information)

Comment: I would recommend enabling the compose key:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key

Comment: Depending on the keyboard layout you use, you can choose variants with dead keys, e.g. Hit ` then e to produce è.